# Fluents Assertions: exclude field recursively

Tags: c#, fluent-assertions

I have simple class, for example

```
class Person {
   public string Name;
   public string LastName;
   public Person Parent;
   public static int IdCounter = 0;
   public int Id;

   public Person(string name, string lastName, Person parent) {
      Name = name;
      LastName = lastName;
      Parent = parent;
      Id = IdCounter++;
   }
}
```

And in test I wanna compare person I get from somewhere with expected Person like this:

```cs
var expectedPerson = new Person ("John","Galecky", new Person("Sheldon", "Cooper", null));
var actualPerson = PersonGenerator.GetCurrentPerson();
```

And I wanna to compare them recursively excluding Id field, what means for Parents too

```cs
actualPerson.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedPerson, (options) =>
            {
                options.Excluding(t => t.Id);
            });
```

But ofc this works only for first level Person, how can I exclude Id field for Parent and for his Parent and e.t.c while FluentAssertion can go into recursion (10 levels in documentation)? 
In this Example it seems quite unreasonable, but I need exactly to do this, how it can be done?

Comment: What's your expected result ? Your question in confusing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To recursively exclude a member you'll have to use [`Excluding(Expression<Func<IMemberInfo, bool>> predicate)`](https://fluentassertions.com/objectgraphs/#equivalency-comparison-behavior) which let's you pattern match the path to the member to exclude.

E.g. you want to exclude

- Id
- Parent.Id
- Parent.Parent.Id
- ...

As every path ends with `Id` you can use

```cs
Excluding(ctx => ctx.SelectedMemberPath.EndsWith("Id"))
```

```cs
var expectedPerson = new Person("John", "Galecky", new Person("Sheldon", "Cooper", null));
var actualPerson = new Person("John", "Galecky", new Person("Sheldon", "Cooper", null));

actualPerson.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expectedPerson, options =>
    options.Excluding(ctx => ctx.SelectedMemberPath.EndsWith("Id")));
```

Be aware that this is pure string matching.
If e.g. another member has an `Id` property you *want* to include, you can use this way to ensure that it only matches the root Id or any Parent.Id.

```
Regex.IsMatch(ctx.SelectedMemberPath, @"^(Parent\.)*Id$")
```

Comment: Thanks! By the way, is it correct and normal way to do it?

Comment: The `Excluding` overload looking at `SelectedMemberPath` is the best available way to do recursive matching. See e.g. https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/issues/1153. The regex example is the best way I can come up with to match *exactly* to the `Person.Id` and nothing else.